# The RecyclerView automatically refresh(invalidate) itself when I add a view

Tags: android

My situation is a bit special, because I use windowManager to drawOverLay instead of the normal method. And I encounter a problem that, I have a recyclerView in a framlayout(called rootlayout), and when I add a new view to the rootlayout, the recyclerView in it will blink once and scroll back to the top(it seems like it invalidate itself). Doesn't anyone has any idea about this situation? Thanks

this is the code which I add bottom sheet(the new layout)

```
private void showSelectionLayout(String title, List<String> options){
    selectionLayout = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet, rootLayout, false);
    sheetContent = (LinearLayout)selectionLayout.findViewById(R.id.sheet_content);
    RecyclerView sheetList = (RecyclerView) selectionLayout.findViewById(R.id.sheet_recycleView);
    sheetCancel = (HeadlineView)selectionLayout.findViewById(R.id.sheet_cancel);
    HeadlineView sheetTitle = (HeadlineView) selectionLayout.findViewById(R.id.sheet_title);

    ScreenUtils.applyDim(selectionLayout);
    sheetContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    sheetCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    selectionLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            selectionLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            final Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getContext(), R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom
            );
            slideUp.setDuration(SHEET_EXPAND_DURATION);
            sheetContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sheetCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sheetContent.startAnimation(slideUp);
            sheetCancel.startAnimation(slideUp);
        }
    });

    selectionLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> dismissSelectionLayout());
    sheetCancel.setOnClickListener(view -> dismissSelectionLayout());
    sheetTitle.setText(String.format(SharedConstants.CONTACT_TITLE, title));

    SheetAdapter adapter = new SheetAdapter(options);
    adapter.setItemClickListener(option -> {
        dismissSelectionLayout();
    });
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    sheetList.setAdapter(adapter);
    sheetList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout);
    rootLayout.addView(selectionLayout);
}
```

Comment: can you post sample of your code?

Comment: I add the source code of how I add the new layout to rootlayout, any other source code you need? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I find why.

because I need to get the itemView of the item user click, so I get the view and call removeAllViews() for its parent in the click listener, and this will cause the recyclerView refresh(invalidate) itself

```
holder.binding.item.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (mItemListener != null) {
            int[] margin = new int[2];
            margin[0] = holder.binding.suggestionCardLayout.getLeft() + ((ViewGroup) holder.itemView.getParent()).getLeft();
            margin[1] = holder.binding.suggestionCardLayout.getTop() + ((ViewGroup) holder.itemView.getParent()).getTop();
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) holder.binding.suggestionCardLayout.getParent());
            ((ViewGroup) holder.binding.suggestionCardLayout.getParent()).removeAllViews();
            mItemListener.onShortcutClicked(card.getShortcut(), holder.binding.suggestionCardLayout, margin);
        }
    });
```

so, just delete removeAllViews() function is OK

```
holder.binding.item.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (mItemListener != null) {
            int[] margin = new int[2];
            margin[0] = holder.binding.suggestionCardLayout.getLeft() + ((ViewGroup) holder.itemView.getParent()).getLeft();
            margin[1] = holder.binding.suggestionCardLayout.getTop() + ((ViewGroup) holder.itemView.getParent()).getTop();
            mItemListener.onShortcutClicked(card.getShortcut(), holder.binding.suggestionCardLayout, margin);
        }
    });
```